# Font-Awesome version 6 icons not showing

Tags: html, font-awesome

First example is not showing, but second example is showing. Why?

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.1.1/css/all.min.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <i class="fa-solid fa-square-info"></i> NOT SHOWING
    <i class="fas fa-info-circle"></i> SHOWING
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please [read carefully](https://fontawesome.com/icons/square-info?s=solid) before you use it. They said _Start Using This Pro Icon_.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is because the icon `fa-solid fa-square-info` is a PRO icon and it's not available for use in the free version of font-awesome. So the icon is not rendering. Alternatively you can try using [Material Design Icons](https://materialdesignicons.com) which is open source and free to use.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem using the current version 6. I am using the free version. You have to get the Kit>Manage Kits>Settings and copy the javascript link and your all set.

No need to download all the files and folders to put it on your site. Attaching the js script will do just fine :)

Comment: I have to change the link to `all.js` (was: `fontawesome.js`) to show some icon in free version of Font Awesome 6